# New at html, facing an error on my website

Tags: php, css, html

Ok so I made my website in html, but theres some sort of white line bars located on the top and im not sure why they are there i think i made an error in my source code, if someone could please help figure out why they are there thatd be great (im new at html, only know the basics)

[Heres a picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcYmX.png)

```html
<font size="4" color="white">
 <h1>This Website Was Created By The One And Only SaucyFam
</font>
</div>

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.silvergames.com/slitherio">
 <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.silvergames.com/slitherio" hreflang="en">
 <link rel="alternate" href="http://de.silvergames.com/slitherio" hreflang="de">
 <link rel="alternate" href="http://ru.silvergames.com/slitherio" hreflang="ru">
 
 <title>Slither.io | Game 2 Play Online</title>
 
 <link href="http://i2.silvergames.com/css/n7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://i2.silvergames.com/l-switch/css/polyglot-language-switcher-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="New Games" href="/feed/rss.xml" />
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://i1.silvergames.com/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://i1.silvergames.com/l-switch/js/jquery/jquery-polyglot.language.switcher.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://i2.silvergames.com/js/advertisement.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://i1.silvergames.com/js/vote.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://i2.silvergames.com/js/swfobject.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://i3.silvergames.com/js/fullscreen_full.js"></script>

 </form>
 <div class="clear_both"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="polyglot-language-switcher" data-grid-columns="1" data-anim-effect="fade" data-open-mode="click">
 
 <ul style="display:none">
  <li>
   <a href="http://www.silvergames.com/slitherio" title="English" data-lang-id="en">
    <img src="http://i1.silvergames.com/l-switch/images/flags/us.png" alt="English">English
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="http://de.silvergames.com/slitherio" title="Deutsch" data-lang-id="de">
    <img src="http://i2.silvergames.com/l-switch/images/flags/de.png" alt="Deutsch">Deutsch
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="http://ru.silvergames.com/slitherio" title="Русский" data-lang-id="ru">
    <img src="http://i3.silvergames.com/l-switch/images/flags/ru.png" alt="Русский">Русский
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div class="clear_both"></div>
 </div></div>
 
 <div id="menu_2" style="display:none;">
  <div id="items_2"></div> <div class="clear_both">
 </div>
 </div></div>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="container" style="width:1260px;">
   <div id="game-box" style="">
    <div id="game" >
     <div id="game_embed" style="width:700px;height:500px;">
      <iframe src="http://slither.io/" id="swf" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="background-color:#000000;border:nvone;" width="700" height="500"></iframe>
     </div >
    </div>
    <div id="game-features">
     <div id="vote-buttons">
      </button>&nbsp;
      <span id="voted"></span>
     </div>
     <div id="zoom-button">
      <div style="cursor:pointer;" id="fullscreen">
       <img src="http://i1.silvergames.com/i/fullscreen.png" title="Fullscreen" alt="fullscreen">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="walkthrough-button">
      <div style="" id="walkthrough">
       <a href="/slitherio/walkthrough" target="" title="Slither.io Walkthrough">
        <img src="http://i1.silvergames.com/i/walkthrough.png" alt="walkthrough">
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="clear_both"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="game-related-box">
    <div class="hot_box">
     <div id="dynamic-editorial">
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="/goodgame-empire" target="">
         <img src="http://agar.io/img/1200x630.png      " width="110" height="70" alt=":D"/>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="/goodgame-empire" target="">Unblocked Agario  </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="dynamic-editorial-2">
      <ul>
       <li>
     </div>
     <div style="position: absolute; top: 530px; right: 220px; width: 250px; height: 150px; background-color: ">
      <font size="4" color="white">
       <h1>
        << Click Here To Go Into FullScreen Mode
     </div>
     <div style="position: absolute; top: 200px; right: 233px; width: 240px; height: 150px; background-color: ;">
      <font size="4" color="white">
       <h1>SaucyFams Very Own Server IP Mods, Coming Soon:

        <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:70px; LEFT:10px; WIDTH:300px; HEIGHT:200px" SRC="http://slitheriogameplay.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/slither-io-mods-300x167.png">
        </p>
        </body>
</html>
<html>
<body background="http://slither.io/s/bg45.jpg">
```

Comment: The white bar lines are under "

<< Click Here To Go Into FullScreen Mode
SaucyFams Very Own Server IP Mods, Coming Soon:"

Comment: Without showing us your code, it'll be quite impossible for us to see what's causing the issue. Because there could be any number of reasons for it.

Comment: added html code above, id be gratefeful if you could take a look thank u

Comment: I've tried looking at it, but your code is so full of errors and mistakes, that I don't even know where to begin. You're including a LOT of javascript files and stylesheets.. You're coding outside of the html elements, inside the head elements.. lots of closing elements that have no opening elements.. it's quite a mess in there! Fixing all the problems is probebly easier by rewriting the entire code.

Comment: im not sure id be able to rewrite the entire code. im actually not that familiar with a lot of the tags on there, and i got most of them from online. Maybe this could be a bit too highskilled for me? its more the <div> tags im confused about

Comment: maybe i could rewrite the top part of the code? most likely the causing of the white lines

Comment: The cause of the white lines is most likely inside one of your CSS files. You can see those 3 underneath the line `<title>Slither.io | Game 2 Play Online</title>`. Now HTML is probebly as basic as it gets. You can easily learn it. But currently you're jumping in the middle of the ocean without learning how to swim first. If you want, I can spend a bit of time teaching you a few things. But we need to setup a Teamviewer session for that.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the 10px padding-bottom.
In file n7.css , line 31, you'll see the following:

```
#content {
background-color: #ffffff;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Change by:

```
#content {
background-color: #ffffff;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Not very familiar with css, made in html. can u take a look at the coding and help me from there. i added the html above^^

Answer (score 1):

The reason of problem here;

```
#content {
background-color: #ffffff;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

But I see, "you are not very familiar with css" so this code is in a file of your server (http://i2.silvergames.com/css/n7.css). Please go there, find the code above and change:

```
#content {
background-color: #ffffff;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: If you take a look at the picture, you'll see that it's some free webhosting site. The CSS files and other code seem to be simply copy / pasted from another website. It's very likely he has no control over those files at all.

Comment: I noticed now. I tried my chance anyway. :)

Comment: Well someone else already gave the anser, but I can see you're still very new here and just trying to get some reputation. I'll give you an upvote so you're one step closer :)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get some reputation. Thank you :)